# Insert Data into Android SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

This code doesn't show any error during compiletime or runtime but the values is not get inserted to database. ***Please guide me*** 
I was new to android programing field. This code doesn't show any error during compiletime or runtime but the values is not get inserted to database.

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                values.put("username",u_name);
                values.put("password", pass);
                db.insert("login", null, values);
```

Comment: You're actual call to the insertion looks correct to me. Is your database schema setup correctly before you insert? From the way I'm reading it... it could be inserting into a completely empty database? You may need to implement a DBhelper that creates the structure on onCreate http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-creating-a-sqlite-database

Comment: if I use update instead of insert this full code is working.

Answer (score 0):

you are not calling the regs() function. call it like

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reg);
    regs();
}
```

and change the regs() function signature to

```
public void regs(View v){
```

to

```
public void regs(){
```

since you are not using `v` variable of `View`

Comment: forceclose app :(   E/AndroidRuntime(379): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: regs